# Show-labels in vuetifys sparkline

Tags: vuetify.js

I cant get the property show-labels to work. I assume that the labels will be under the value, like -

JAN (label)
200 (value)

I can get both label and value but not together. I have tried :show-label and without : and both "true" and true.

```
        <v-sparkline
      :labels="months"
      :value="value"
      show-labels=true
      color="rgba(255, 255, 255, .7)"
      height="100"
      padding="24"
      stroke-linecap="round"
      smooth
    >
```

Comment: can we see what  `months` and `value` looks like? It worked for me

Comment: Shouldn't it be :show-labels="true", in front there is a colon?

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't get any labels either.

Answer (score 0):

So I believe the labels are there, just white. I'm not 100% why but in some vuetify examples `primary--text` is added to svg and the labels appear. If you add `class="primary--text"` to your `v-sparkline` your labels should appear (assuming your primary--text color isn't white.